# Confusing the session codeigniter function, the page logout() function doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-variables

I have tried the codeigniter session in this article https://www.malasngoding.com/membuat-login-dengan-codeigniter/ with the following code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller
{

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *    - or -
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *    - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    //Login sudah bisa
    function action_login()
    {
        $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
        $user_password = $this->input->post('user_password');
        $wheredatasession = array(
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'user_password' => md5($user_password)
        );

        $cek = $this->user_model->ceklogintolong($wheredatasession)->num_rows();
        if ($cek > 0) {
            $data_session = array(
                'nama' => $user_email,
                'status' => "login"
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
//          $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
//          echo "Berhasil";
//          print_r($where);
            redirect('User/homeinfouser');

        } else {
            echo "Pass uname salah";
//          print_r($where);
        }
    }

    //Login menuju home info sudah bisa http://localhost/webcismppgri/User/homeinfouser
    function homeinfouser()
    {
//      echo "OK Tolong";
//      $hasil['print'] = $this->user_model->getinfo();
        $hasil['print'] = $this->user_model->getinfo();
//      print_r($hasil);
//      $judul_user['juduldashboard'] = "Dashboard User";
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/header');
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/index',$judul_user);
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/page _informasi', $judul_user);
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/page_informasi', $hasil);
//      $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/footer');
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/footer');
//      var_dump($hasilview);
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/indextesdata',$hasil);
    }

    //Fungsi Logout
    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Landing', 'refresh');
    }



}
```

Tried to click the navigation back to the chrome browser page (right arrow navigation or forward), it can still be opened with the previously accessed page, even though I have provided the following code

```
// Logout function
function logout ()
{
$ this-> session-> sess_destroy ();
redirect ('Landing', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: you need to check the session variable are set or not on each request it will work

Comment: How does it work? Using vardump (), print_r ()?

Comment: in each request, you need to check whether your session variables are set or not that's it

Comment: @M.Hemant I'm more confused, please give an example here

Comment: **using md5 for password hash is bad practice**: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function. In your function homeinfouser, check if there is a session, if not then send to login. That resolves your problem

Comment: @Vickel Sorry I don't have an idea of ​​the solution you provide, please provide a real example in the form of source code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct one looks like this..

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller
{

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *    - or -
     *        http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *    - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->library('session');
        if (!$this->session->userdata('status')) {
            redirect('Landing','refresh');
        }
    }

    //Login sudah bisa
    function action_login()
    {
        $user_email = $this->input->post('user_email');
        $user_password = $this->input->post('user_password');
        $wheredatasession = array(
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'user_password' => md5($user_password)
        );

        $cek = $this->user_model->ceklogintolong($wheredatasession)->num_rows();
        if ($cek > 0) {
            $data_session = array(
                'nama' => $user_email,
                'status' => "login"
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
//          $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
//          echo "Berhasil";
//          print_r($where);
            redirect('User/homeinfouser');

        } else {
            echo "Pass uname salah";
//          print_r($where);
        }
    }

    //Login menuju home info sudah bisa http://localhost/webcismppgri/User/homeinfouser
    function homeinfouser()
    {
//      echo "OK Tolong";
//      $hasil['print'] = $this->user_model->getinfo();
        $hasil['print'] = $this->user_model->getinfo();
//      print_r($hasil);
//      $judul_user['juduldashboard'] = "Dashboard User";
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/header');
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/index',$judul_user);
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/page _informasi', $judul_user);
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/page_informasi', $hasil);
//      $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/footer');
        $this->load->view('templates/sbadmin/footer');
//      var_dump($hasilview);
//      $this->load->view('templates/dashboard/indextesdata',$hasil);
    }

    //Fungsi Logout
    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('Landing', 'refresh');
    }



}
```

it worked according to the scenario, thank you for participating.

Comment: If you place the "check if session exists" part in the constructor, this controller cannot contain any functions for users which are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `User`, you need to check if a "reserved" function is called (a function, which needs the user to be logged in) that there is an existing session.

In your example, if you hit the back button, you come back to the function `homeinfouser()`, but as there is no check for a valid session, it gets executed, even if you are logged out.

Just place a small code to check for the session:

```
function homeinfouser()
{
    // no Session, no play
    if( !isset($_SESSION['status']) ){
        redirect('Landing', 'refresh');
        exit();
    }
    //... your other code
}
```

**sidenote: using md5 for password hash is bad practice**. Concerning password hashing, please read [How weak is MD5 as a password hashing function ?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function)